# How to get the authenticated user info and use in all controllers and services?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm using angularFireAuth and I want to retrieve the logged in user's info and use in
all the controllers or services when the app is initial.

Currently, I used this in every controller but i having some problem.

```
$scope.$on("angularFireAuth:login", function(evt, user){ 
  console.log(user);
});
```

The callback will not call if it is not a full page load or return null when app initial.

I need some tips for how can I return the authenticated user's info so I can use when app is initial and in all the controllers and services.

Example

When in controller or services

- `$scope.auth.user.id` will return user's ID
- `$scope.auth.user.name` will return user's name
- etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with a `userService` for this:

```
angular.module('EventBaseApp').service('userService', function userService() {
    return {
        isLogged: false,
        username: null
    }

});
```

And write a `LoginCtrl` controller:

```
angular.module('EventBaseApp')
  .controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, userService, angularFireAuth) {
    var url = "https://example.firebaseio.com";
    angularFireAuth.initialize(url, {scope: $scope, name: "user"});

    $scope.login = function() {
        angularFireAuth.login("github");

    };
    $scope.logout = function() {
        angularFireAuth.logout();
    };

    $scope.$on("angularFireAuth:login", function(evt, user) {
      userService.username = $scope.user;
      userService.isLogged = true;
    });

    $scope.$on("angularFireAuth:logout", function(evt) {
      userService.isLogged = false;
      userService.username = null;
    });
});
```

Inject the `userService` anywhere you want the user.

My app that am currently working on that uses this - https://github.com/manojlds/EventBase/blob/master/app/scripts/controllers/login.js

Based on ideas presented here - http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/deal-with-users-authentication-in-an-angularjs-web-app

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure quite what your question is.  but if you are looking to authorise once rather than in each controller, you can put the code into the module instead and put it into the $rootScope.

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp').run(
    function ($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.user = null;

        $rootScope.$on("angularFireAuth:login", function (evt, user) {
            $rootScope.user = user;

        });
    });
```

Comment: I put it in a service. Then I run it in .run() and I call $scope.user in controller. It always return null, not listening at all.

I created another question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18633691/how-to-use-angularfireauth-values-in-controllers-and-services

Comment: you will have to show your code.  are you injecting the user service into your controller?

Comment: i just looked at your other question.  you are on the right path. the authservice just needs to be injected into your controllers or services where ever you need it.  as it is a singleton, it will only be logged in once.

Comment: @Anton Still not working. Here is the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/lNLhlHh1RET5bxfOB78M?p=preview Please check it, thank you

Comment: the plunker gives a 404 not found error.  is the url correct?