# How to use angularFireAuth values in controllers and services?

Tags: angularjs, angularfire

Let say I put angularFireAuth inside a service.

```
app.factory('authService',
function($rootScope, $timeout, angularFireAuth, FIREBASE_URL) {
    return function() {
        angularFireAuth.initialize(new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL), {
            scope: $rootScope,
            name: 'user',
            path: "/"
        });
        $rootScope.$on('angularFireAuth:login', function _set(evt, user) {
            $timeout(function() {
                $rootScope.auth = {
                    authenticated: true
                   };
            });
         });
        $rootScope.$on('angularFireAuth:logout', function(){
            $timeout(function() {
                $rootScope.auth = {
                    authenticated: false
                   };
            });    
        });
      }
    });
```

Then I initial it in .run()

```
.run(['$rootScope', 'authService', function($rootScope, authService){
  authService();
});
```

My question is how can I use `$scope.auth.authenticated` in other services and controllers.

I `console.log($scope.auth.authenticated)` in controller. It always return false. Seem like it is not listening / watching the login

Or

Can I use $scope.user directly in controller and listening on it?

UPDATE

I created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lNLhlHh1RET5bxfOB78M?p=preview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that $scope.user (and by extension $scope.auth) are not created until the login takes place, which isn't until one clicks the login button. But the console.log event takes place as soon as the controller is created (onDOMReady).

You probably don't need the $scope.auth at all. Firereader is using that because it needs some additional data put into the user object and specifically a boolean which is used in an ng-switch statement. In your case, you can probably just use $scope.user, which is set by angularFireAuth and not bother with the $scope.auth object.

So, to summarize, if you move your console.log to wait until the login is completed, it will work as expected:  http://plnkr.co/edit/Bd23DGFtEpqO2g4jo06v?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['firebase']);

app.constant('FIREBASE_URL', 'https://newname.firebaseio.com/');
app.run(['$rootScope', 'authService', function($rootScope, authService){
    authService();
    $rootScope.$watch('auth.authenticated', function() {
        isAuthenticated = $rootScope.auth.authenticated;
    });
}]);

app.factory('authService', [
    '$rootScope',
    '$timeout',
    'angularFireAuth',
    'FIREBASE_URL',

    function($rootScope, $timeout, angularFireAuth, FIREBASE_URL) {
        return function() {
            angularFireAuth.initialize(new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL), {
                scope: $rootScope,
                name: 'user'
            });

            $rootScope.$on('angularFireAuth:login', _log);

            function _log(evt, user) {
                // this is where $scope.user and $scope.auth will be set
                  console.log($scope.user);
             }
        }
    }
]);



app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, authService, angularFireAuth) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.login = function(){
    angularFireAuth.login('facebook');
  }

  $scope.logout = function(){
    angularFireAuth.logout();
  }

  // angularFireAuth hasn't returned yet at this point
  // console.log($scope.auth);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your explains. Since that, I will use $scope.user instead. 

By the way, I fixed it by remove $timeout

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Tom Chen's second example I'm using angularfire's auth like so:

```
myapp.controller("UserController", ["$scope", "$firebase", "$firebaseSimpleLogin",       function($scope, $firebase, $firebaseSimpleLogin) {
var ref = new Firebase("https://XXXXXX.firebaseio.com/");
$scope.auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(ref);

$scope.$watch('auth', function(newAuth, oldAuth){
    console.log(newAuth, oldAuth);
    // logged in, 
    // can reference newAuth.user.id
  }, true);

}]);
```

UPDATE

This example is also a call back

```
$scope.$on("$firebaseSimpleLogin:login", function(e, user) {
  // can reference user.id 
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your answer would be more helpful if it was formatted in an easy to read way.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Yes new to commenting here. How's the formatting now?

Answer (score 0):

One reason that i can think on why this is not working could be that the local scope is shadowing the variable declared on $rootScope. Maybe there has been an assignment to the local scope object `auth`. You can very much verify this in firebug or chrome tools by putting some breakpoints and verify values for both `$rootScope.auth` and `$scope.auth`.

Better to check when the auth completes within a child scope.

Comment: I found something weird. When I do a full reload it will not return the logged in data. But when I use browser back / pre button which is angular `$location.path` (part reload) then I will get the logged in data. Do you have any idea?

Comment: On full reload the framework re-initializes whereas when in anuglarjs context and you change page with back or location it is only swaps one view with another if there is a `ng-view` declared.

Comment: Yes I know. But the listening data only return via $ location not when via full reload

Answer (score 0):

I would replace `angularFire` with [`angular-on-fire`](https://github.com/tomchentw/angular-on-fire) and use the provided `fireEntry` service.

```
module('app.auth', ['angular-on-fire'])
.constant({FirebaseUrl: "https://YOUR_FB_NAME.firebaseIO.com/"})
.run(['$rootScope', 'fireEntry', function($rootScope, fireEntry){
  var auth = {};
  $rootScope.auth = auth;
  fireEntry(auth);
}]]);
```

So, any update to `auth` will reflected in the `$rootScope` auth variable.
If user logged in, `auth` will contain user information provided by FirebaseSimpleLogin. Once logged out, `auth` will be empty.

You can now watch on `$rootScope.auth` to receive any auth update!

```
module('app.ctrl', ['app.auth']).controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.$watch('auth', function(newAuth, oldAuth){
    console.log(newAuth, oldAuth);
  }, true);
}]);
```

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a shot.