# How to read Current logged-in user using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Could someone help me, how to read the current logged-in user id, name using Angularjs ?

Comment: Refer:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437120/how-to-get-the-authenticated-user-info-and-use-in-all-controllers-and-services

Answer (score 0):

Well, on a callback from service, that stores your users, you can put all the required credentials in i.e. [angular-storage](https://github.com/auth0/angular-storage) and use it further in your application